Can Nusach be changed throughout the day?
Is there an issue with davening, for example, Nusach HaArizal for Shacharit, and then Mincha according to Nusach Ashkenaz?

I assume you won't lead the prayers, and most rabbis would probably say that as long as you don't disturb the congregation, you can pray in your own nusach. But you should rather talk to your rabbi, tell him all the relevant details, and he'd tell you what's the best for you to do!

While what Kazi suggested is the most practical advice. There is also the view that the siddur as it was introduced by the Alter Rebbe represents shaar kollel and thus can be used by anyone. This is explained in full in the intro to the Tehilas Hashem siddur with English

I won't vote to open until more details are added. Does this mean one is going to go to 2 different shuls, but still use the siddur of their own nusach, or does it mean one is also going use different siddurim, one for each nusach?

@Dude Virtually anyone outside of Chabad is not maskim that tho

There is the added scenario that if you find yourself in another shul that davens an alternative nusach, halacha states you should daven that shul's nusach

@ezra so? It's a valid shita and that's why I included it
